# FCM Web send message succeeds but nothing appears in Browser

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-notifications

I am sending following Notification

```
Authorization:key=A.....
Content-Type:application/json    
{
    "to" : "cBx_ErhkhNw:APA91bEzwHvZ2daEK15Y3A0VAprxPV-4GGq10FjlrFnHzCs8xSJXz2lATjh9AoLRQvnSseT6r4ggApC6TbtD9M_sI_BDDmycZ1TEVn0HaF5pAABeSbHqcOK-kmkPqOve1VThUaUIXQy4",

      "notification": {
        "title": "Test Nachricht",
        "body": "This is a message from FCM to web"
      },
      "priority": "high",
      "webpush": {
      "fcm_options": {
        "link": "https://dummypage.com"
      }
    }

}
```

And have following code:

app.js

```
 // Initialize Firebase
 var config = {
     apiKey: "<KEY>",
     authDomain: "<AUTH_DOMAIN>",
     databaseURL: "<DB_URL>",
     projectId: "atlas-test-35d33",
     storageBucket: "<STORAGE_BUCKET>",
     messagingSenderId: "817272374311"
 };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);
 const messaging = firebase.messaging();
 messaging.usePublicVapidKey("<PUBLIC_KEY>");
 messaging.requestPermission()
     .then(function() {
         console.log("Permission granted");
         return messaging.getToken()
     })
     .then(function(token) {
         console.log(token)
     })
     .catch(function(err) {
         console.log(err)
     })
 console.log("listenting")
 messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
     console.log('Message received. ', payload);
     // ...
 });
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
    // Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

  var config = {
    apiKey: "<KEY>",
    authDomain: "<AUTH_DOMAIN>",
    databaseURL: "https://atlas-test-35d33.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "atlas-test-35d33",
    storageBucket: "<STORAGE_BUCKET>",
    messagingSenderId: "817272374311"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

When I try to send a Notification to the fcm Server I get following response:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 5394725759940263108,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1552646324437940%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Which seems, like everything is fine for me. But I dont receive anything in my Web application. I just hardcoded the "to" token for testing purposes but I dont think thats the Problem.

Do you have any clue whats the problem, or is there any debug possibility.

Thanks!

Comment: they arent your real keys rights?

Comment: if they are you might want to delete this post... and reset your keys.

Comment: They were justing testing keys but thank you a lot! Do you have any idea whats my Problem (apart from my keys)

Comment: firebase isn't my forte, unfortionaly